# How to read only Sales files from the Region folder?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have CSV files inside the Region folder.

How to read only Sales files from the Region folder with Python Pandas?

I searched but did not find answer.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
USA_Sales_20190716.csv
USA_Sales_20190715.csv
USA_Sales_20190714.csv
USA_Budget_20190716.csv
USA_Budget_20190715.csv
USA_Budget_20190714.csv

UK_Sales_20190716.csv
UK_Sales_20190715.csv
UK_Sales_20190714.csv
UK_Budget_20190716.csv
UK_Budget_20190715.csv
UK_Budget_20190714.csv

GER_Sales_20190716.csv
GER_Sales_20190715.csv
GER_Sales_20190714.csv
GER_Budget_20190716.csv
GER_Budget_20190715.csv
GER_Budget_20190714.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `glob` module and `pandas` to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

sales_dir = r'c:\yourpath'

sales_files = glob.glob(path + r'\*sales*.csv')

dfs = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in sales_files]

pd.concat(dfs)
```